Two independent Blazor tasks, pause one until the other completes
I need to complete one Task before another Task completes. Both are called by Blazor, to distinct components, and therefore I have no knowledge or control over which is called first and therefore the must complete task could be complete before the delay until task has even been called.
Here's the specifics. I have a form that uses <DxFormLayoutTabPages> that provides a tabbed set of pages, each page has components in it. This component has an ActiveTabIndexChanged event.
In one of the pages I have a <DxRichEdit> component. It has a LostFocus event.
What happens is when the user switches from the tab with the RichEdit to another tab the RichEdit LostFocus event is called and the TabPages ActiveTabIndexChanged is called. When the ActiveTabIndexChanged completes the RichEdit is disposed, regradless of the state of the LostFocus event.
In the LostFocus event I call await RichEditDesc.SaveDocumentAsync(); and that, before returning, calls DocumentContentChanged event passing the editor's document. In that call I save off the contents for when the user later clicks [Save].
Now if LostFocus completes before ActiveTabIndexChanged completes, life is great and I have the document contents saved off. But if ActiveTabIndexChanged completes before the call to SaveDocumentAsync completes, the RichEdit component is disposed, the call to DocumentContentChanged does not happen, and I've lost the document content.
The easy solution is:
private async Task OnActiveTabIndexChanged(int idx)
{
    if (ActiveIndex == 5)
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    ActiveIndex = idx;
}

But I dislike this because first, makes for a UI that freezes for a second and second, what about the rare situation where 1 second is not long enough.
The problem I am struggling with is, based on logging I added, I have seen both:

ActiveTabIndexChanged
LostFocus

and

LostFocus
ActiveTabIndexChanged

So setting an int, signal, whatever - I don't see where/how to set that, to then await its completion in ActiveTabIndexChanged. I can't set it up when the form is created because people can go to the RichEdit tab, then another tab, then back to the RichEdit tab.
This is not a Blazor question, unless it has something I'm not aware of to handle situations like this. This is a question of synchronizing two tasks where I have no control over what order the events are called in, nothing to tell me they're about to be called, and this can all happen multiple times.
And to keep this simple, I just listed the above. But the same issue occurs if the user clicks [Save] when on the tab with the RichEdit. In that case there's an AppointmentFormClosing event. Same issue with LoseFocus. So the LoseFocus part of this has to work with either of the two other events being called.
Very simple razor:
<DxScheduler AppointmentFormClosing="AppointmentFormClosing">
  <AppointmentFormLayout>
    <DxFormLayoutTabPages ActiveTabIndex="@ActiveIndex" ActiveTabIndexChanged="OnActiveTabIndexChanged">
      <DxFormLayoutTabPage Caption="Details">
        <DxRichEdit LostFocus="OnRichEditDescLostFocus" ModifiedChanged="OnDocumentDescModified" DocumentContentChanged="OnDocumentDescChanged">
      </DxFormLayoutTabPage>
    </DxFormLayoutTabPages>
  </AppointmentFormLayout>
</<DxScheduler>


Where in relationship to each other are the methods?  Same component, parent/child?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I added it, keeping it very simple. TIA

I came up with a simple/clean solution. Key is that in this case it does not matter if I call await RichEditDesc.SaveDocumentAsync(); multiple times. The DxRichEdit ignores the call after the first time because the content is no longer modified. But even if it processed it multiple times, all that would happen is that I save of the byte array again.
So in both ActiveTabIndexChanged and AppointmentFormClosing (as well as LostFocus), I call SaveDocumentAsync(). It will get called twice. That works fine.
Not need for any complex use of a shared int, semaphore, etc.
Update: Per MrC's answer & comments below, I agree 100% with him that requiring code to be called twice is almost always a very bad sign. But this does not require the code be called twice.
In this case it will always call one of the two events. It will often call both of the two events. If there is no downside to the save being called twice, then putting it in both events works.

It's interesting how often the solution for what looks like a complex problem is actually simple. Leaving this Q&A up as others may hit something similar.

I'd not be happy with code that needs to run several times to make sure something happened.  It's a bad code smell.
I would have thought it unlikely that LostFocus is run before OnActiveTabIndexChanged unless it's in the bind chain where say DocumentContentChanged is called first, and DocumentContentChanged is a yielding async method.  As the codebase is a closed book I can't review the code and confirm.  My DevExpress demo licence ran out a long while ago!
If it were then I suspect the binding would also not have yet run, and OnDocumentDescChanged not run and set the value.  You need to check.  Make sure you're logging in the right place - before any awaits.
What you should be able to do is something like this using a Task.
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.SwitchPage">Switch Page</button>

<InputText @onblur="this.LostFocus" @bind-Value="_value" />

@if (_isNotCompleted)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Awaiting Task Completion</div>
}

@code {
    private string? _value;
    private Task _awaitTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    private bool _isNotCompleted => !_awaitTask.IsCompleted;

    private async Task LostFocus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lost Focus");
        _awaitTask = Task.Delay(3000);

        await _awaitTask;

        Console.WriteLine("Lost Focus Completed");
        _awaitTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task SwitchPage()
    {
        await _awaitTask;

        Console.WriteLine("Switch Page");
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }
}

If this doesn't work and proves that the order is variable, then check the order in which ModifiedChanged, OnDocumentDescChanged and LostFocus are called using console logging.  Once you understand that, you can choose the appropriate Task to await.

I've logged the events being called and seen it occur in either order. I 100% agree with you that requiring code be called twice is very bad. But this is different, it's that there's no problem if it's called twice. Works great if it's only called once, but there's no downside if it's called twice.

Agreed.  You need to do what's necessary to build a solution which works within the your chosen framework (I've had a few issues lately with MudBlazor and FluentUI).  The fundamental problem would appear to be that an event associated with a gain in focus is fired before a loss in focus event for the element losing focus.  Bad, but not being a DevExpress man, it's not my concern.
